# What is the proper name for a container with these requirements?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, containers

I need to implement additional container for my library. I need it for holding profile points in my profiler module. Everything is ready to begin coding, however, I am not sure what is the proper name for this kind of container.

What I need, is data structure described as following:

- It's a 'multi-level' container (entries can have children).
- There is no root node.
- At the 'top level' it holds list of elements.
- Elements are stored in order they were added.
- Each node can have any number of child nodes.

Example usage:

```
Container c;
c.push(5);
c.push(7);
c.push_level(); //now, new elements will be added as children of '7'.
c.push(3);
c.push(14);
c.pop_level();
c.push(6); //this entry will be added to 'root list'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like a forest. its a set of trees

Comment: How is `c` itself not the root node?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I was talking about root node inside container itself. Container represents LIST of elements and each of these elements can have multiple children (and this applies recursively).

Comment: @pippin1289 Make that an answer, it's the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a forest. A forest is essentially a set of trees, each with their own root. Your first level of your container is the set of root nodes in the forest, and then all children are described in lower levels.

Answer (score 0):

Everything except the "Elements are stored in order they were added" corresponds with that of an R-tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: R-trees are balenced, yet the OP said nothing about it being balenced. Also there is no mention of "nearby" nodes by the OP.

Comment: True, then I would also suggest your name of "forest", just because it's a normal tree, except that it has several roots

Comment: @ProgM That's exactly what I am talking about. These container is in fact list (double-linked) of elements and all of them are roots with multiple child nodes (list of trees?).